# Why is being a Dragon Slayer a big deal?

Tags: fairy-tail

### Spoilers

During the story arc where Laxus is putting on his "entertainment" for the festival, it is revealed that...

> He is a Dragon Slayer

After this Natsu and others seem to be more worried about him.  Maybe it is just me, but it seemed similar to Goku going Super Saiyan or something.

Why does being a Dragon Slayer seem to make the situation worse?

Comment: the answer itself involves spoilers, do you still want to know?

Comment: @ton.yeung Unfortunately Netflix only had the first season.  It just seemed weird that everyone though of Laxus as being such a powerhouse, but after mentioning that everyone gets even more afraid of him.

Comment: that really doesn't answer the question, do you not plan on watching the second season if/when it does come out? I believe the mangas are also translated.

Comment: @ton.yeung You went and made me all worried about it now :P  I think I would rather have an answer.  I'll likely forget by the time any more seasons are put on one of the services I use.

Comment: SPOILER: dragon slayers *are* kind of like super saiyans, so they're extremely rare, due to abilities unique to dragon slayers, they're a lot more dangerous. Also, since Natsu is looking for his "dad", and dragon slayers need to be trained by dragons, Laxus is an important clue. I think I was able to write this without spoilers. I'm too lazy to bring all the details together for a real answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the Laxus's entertainment arc, it was unknown what type of magic he had. Normally all mages in fairy tail have a limit to how much magic they can use.

For eg- Capricorn helps Lucy to increase her magic stamina.

But the only exception to this rule are the dragon slayers who learnt their magic from dragons and gain their power by eating their element.

For eg- Natsu eats fire, Gazeel eats iron and Wendy eats air.

Now during the fight with Laxus, Natsu an Gazeel are unable to fight him as he is too overpowered. But they must be hoping that Laxus will eventually lose his magic stamina and then they can beat him. But then it was disclosed Laxus is a Lightening Dragon Slayer. That makes him completely invincible as he can gain his power by just eating his element and can battle continuously. And that would make the situation worse.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking two questions. Number one is...

> Why is being a Dragon Slayer a big deal?

And Number Two is...

> Why does being a Dragon Slayer seem to make the situation worse?

Dragon Slayers are a unique type of people who utilize a form of Lost Magic, Dragon Slayer Magic. It was a big deal that Laxus was a dragon slayer because...

> It is uncommon for someone to utilise a lost magic or to be a Dragon Slayer and for Natsu it could have been a perfect opportunity to ask if he had been raised by a dragon and if he knew where Igneel was.

Your other question however why does a dragon slayer seem to make a situation worse. I am going to answer this question based on the Fighting Festival Arc. I am not sure what you mean but ill tack a guess at this...

Dragon Slayers did not make the situation worse, they simply could not help due to Frieds [Jutsu Shiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Jutsu_Shiki) which prevented Natsu, Gajeel and The Master from participating in the carnival and freeing the girls who were turned to stone by Ever Green.

Comment: To the rest of the guild they probably didn't know Laxus knew dragon slaying magic and the only others who could combat his magic being behind Fried's barrier

Comment: On the other hand, Fairy Tale is notorious for the collateral damage they inflict when doing jobs, imagine the damage just Nasu causes by himself, then add Gajeel after he join and the damage will get worse, now add in the discovery that the entire time Laxus had dragon slaying magic, 3 dragon slayers in a guild who does more damage in the process of doing good, quite sure that will make collateral damage situation worse lol

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the second part. Was asking more of "Why is Laxus being a dragon hunter make him scarier than he previously was." After all, he had already beaten both Natsu and Gajeel when they tanned up against him.  Somehow finding out he is a dragon slayer makes him more powerful?

Comment: I just took a shot at it anyway. I wasn't sure what the OP was referring to so just took a stab at giving him the best possible answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @DavidStarkey It doesn't make him powerful. but dragon slayer magic is lost magic. its weakness is unknown. and dragon slayer magic can grow infinitely just by eating your element. Now consider the situation where natsu an gazeel are hoping that laxus will drain all his magic power and then they can beat him, but laxus turns out to be dragon slayer himself with virtually limit less power. so that would make him look more powerful as his magic wont drain out completely ever.

Comment: @Sp0T that's a great explanation. You should make it an answer